# Redireccion con AJAX a PHP

Tags: php, ajax

Estoy intentando redireccionar con AJAX al hacer click en un botón:

```
<input type='button' id='consultar-todos' value='Consultar todos'>
```

El script está en un documento llamado consultarUsu.js y está correctamente referenciado en el documento PHP donde está el botón, al final del body.

```
    <script src='../ajavascript/consultarUsu.js'></script>
  </body>
```

El script es el siguiente:

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#consultar-todos').click(function() {
       console.log('hola');
       $.ajax({
        url: '../negocio/todosUsuarios.php',
        type: 'POST',
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        console.log(xhr);
        }
        });
       });
     });
```

Hace unos días ha funcionado correctamente, el documento PHP al que redirecciono funciona correcto si accedo manualmente por así decirlo. El script no me está redireccionando pero no he cambiado rutas. Hasta antes de la petición ajax funciona porque el console.log("hola") se muestra.

La estructura que tengo de archivos es :

GestorPedidos/ (root con 3 carpetas)

- ajavascript/consultarUsu.js
- negocio/todosUsuarios.php
- presentacion/administrador.php

Con una redirección **window.location.href="../negocio/todosUsuarios.php";** funciona claro, pero funcionaba igual con la petición ajax y la idea era familiarizarme con este tipo de paso de información.

Answer (score 0):

Primero verifica que la URL funciona: `http://localhost/GestorPedidos/negocio/todosUsuarios.php`

Luego modifica la URL en ajax:
`url: 'GestorPedidos/negocio/todosUsuarios.php'` o
`url: '/GestorPedidos/negocio/todosUsuarios.php'`